# How do I increase my percentage of Clergymen

Tags: victoria-2

In Victoria 2:A House Divided the tool tip recommend me to have 2% of my population as clergymen.

How do I increase this percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Victoria 2, Not sure if you noticed that when you click on a province, there the little window that shows up detailing information about the province with little icons, there is a button that allows you to select a "National Focus". Use this to make the state use up a National Focus point in that province to create more Clergy. 2% population as clergymen is used early on in the game to obtain higher literacy and increase research points. Normally I find its only useful up until maybe the 1860s, after that rapid industrialization tends to come in with the available techs then you want to start making a lot of Clerks as they help you more towards the middle-game to end game with increasing profits, literacy and research points.

Also if you click on the population information and select a province, it tells you how much in percentage increases or decreases in any given category. Highlight the clergy section and there are little "Criteria" that must be fulfilled to either INCREASE or DECREASE the percentage of conversions into Clergy

Answer (score 2):

Leon is right. You will need to use your national focus (ideally in your most populous territory) to increase your clergy to 2%.

You can also promote your lower class to clergy quicker by providing them with more personal wealth...eg lower taxes. You can use high taxes to demote your aristocracy in this way also. Job switching from bureaucrats, artisans and officers can also occur if middle class taxes are high, education is well funded and admin/military are poorly funded.

If you have a poor literacy rate or are uncivilised, you will find it beneficial to reach 4% clergy, as this boosts literacy and leads to more research points.